# Ssh- Connection(ssh) to user through one machine only prompts for ssh-password, but through all other machine, it asks for user password

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, ssh-keys

Edit 01/31/2020:

I tried to run ``` sshd -t ```` in two different machines from my side, and I got this:

```
mavridks@rh04359:~$ sshd -t
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 16: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 20: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 21: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 32: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 39: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

and

```
mavridks@rh02500:~/.ssh$ sshd -t
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

---

Edit: After helpful comments, I am specifying here the different names used in the post for the machines and users:

1. me=mavridks
2. admin=sft_wade
3. There are several machines. The machine1=gaia=rh04359
4. All other names are just how the system is pre-configured, so one may have as machine2=draco=rh3805 or machine2=geras=rh4357 . There are other machines too. And perhaps the problem is there: the administrator may have made a mistake over the ssh keys?

I have the ability to connect with ssh to several different remote machines to my account, let's call it me. So to connect, I use

```
ssh me@machine1
ssh me@machine2
```

The connection works ok.

Then, I can also connect to another user having read-write priviledges, lets call the user admin.

Then, from machine1, I can do:

```
ssh admin@machine1
```

. I am prompted to write my ssh password, the same one I used to connect to the remote machine in the first place.

I should be able to do the same from all machines, so , from machine2 too. But when I try the same from machine2 , the ssh password doesn't work and I am prompted for the admin's login password.

Trying to debug, I have executed `ssh -Tvv admin@machine<number>` from both machines. I can see that the first machine checks the ssh password and connects, but the second gives "we send a package..." and then asks for the login password of the admin user.

The results are as follows:

Machine1(the machine that connects):

```
mavridks@rh04359:/etc/ssh$ ssh -Tvv sft_wade@gaia
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gaia" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gaia [127.0.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gaia:22 as 'sft_wade'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dOytZQACouz4KgkzRP2tz76s8+R/r+pWpI+agSnOILc
debug1: Host 'gaia' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mavridks/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for key '/home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gaia ([127.0.1.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-74-generic x86_64)
```

Machine2:

```
mavridks@rh03805:/etc/ssh$ ssh -Tvv sft_wade@draco
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "draco" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to draco [172.16.36.53] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to draco:22 as 'sft_wade'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Zj/8sj/e4MYcgXwpj3ETm9OqnwNtFb+w7HN8OMnAQ88
debug1: Host 'draco' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mavridks/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for key '/home/mavridks/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mavridks/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
sft_wade@draco's password:
```

Now, if I check the .ssh/id_rsa files in both machines, they are the same. Also, the authorized_keys are the same.

Finally, in the folder /etc/ssh/ I get somehow some differences in the files in there(don't know in this is relevant) :

Machine1 contents of /etc/ssh/

```
moduli                ssh_host_dsa_key.pub      ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_config            ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
sshd_config           ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_import_id
sshd_config.ucf-dist  ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_dsa_key      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
```

Machine2 contents of /etc/ssh/

```
moduli                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_config            ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_import_id
ssh_config.orig       ssh_host_ed25519_key      sshd_config
ssh_host_dsa_key      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub  sshd_config.orig
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key
```

So, I can see on the terminal that for some reason, the second machine doesn't complete the process with the ssh key, and it asks me for the admin's login password. Any insight is really appreciated.

---

EDIT: I am adding the information from comments:

From my side, and on machine1 ( the machine that ssh to the admin works):

```
mavridks@rh04359:~/.ssh$ ls -tlr
total 16
-rw------- 1 mavridks mcm 1766 Nov 29 10:01 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 mavridks mcm  413 Nov 29 10:01 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 mavridks mcm 1693 Jan 22 10:37 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1 mavridks mcm 2137 Jan 23 13:49 known_hosts
```

```
mavridks@rh04359:~/.ssh$ stat authorized_keys 
  File: authorized_keys
  Size: 413         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 3ah/58d Inode: 116277297   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2091/mavridks)   Gid: ( 2000/     mcm)
Access: 2020-01-28 12:44:28.420103897 +0100
Modify: 2019-11-29 10:01:08.522918662 +0100
Change: 2019-11-29 10:04:25.994665186 +0100
 Birth: -
```

From my side, and on machine1 ( the machine that ssh to the admin works):

```
mavridks@rh04357:~/.ssh$ ls -tlr
total 16
-rw------- 1 mavridks mcm 1766 Nov 29 10:01 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 mavridks mcm  413 Nov 29 10:01 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 mavridks mcm 1693 Jan 22 10:37 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1 mavridks mcm 2137 Jan 23 13:49 known_hosts
```

and

```
mavridks@rh04357:~/.ssh$ stat authorized_keys 
  File: authorized_keys
  Size: 413         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 33h/51d Inode: 116277297   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2091/mavridks)   Gid: ( 2000/     mcm)
Access: 2020-01-28 12:44:28.420103897 +0100
Modify: 2019-11-29 10:01:08.522918662 +0100
Change: 2019-11-29 10:04:25.994665186 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Finally, the same commands from the side of the admin, on the machine it works( machine1)

```
sft_wade@rh04359:~/.ssh$ ls -tlr
total 40
-rw------- 1 sft_wade mcm   668 Dec 19 08:16 id_dsa
-rw------- 1 sft_wade mcm   610 Dec 19 08:16 id_dsa.pub
-rw------- 1 sft_wade mcm  1679 Dec 19 08:16 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 sft_wade mcm   402 Dec 19 08:16 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 sft_wade mcm  1641 Dec 19 08:16 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 sft_wade mcm 16582 Jan 23 13:16 known_hosts
sft_wade@rh04359:~/.ssh$ stat authorized_keys 
  File: authorized_keys
  Size: 1641        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 3ah/58d Inode: 101449741   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2002/sft_wade)   Gid: ( 2000/     mcm)
Access: 2020-01-22 14:32:30.072151203 +0100
Modify: 2019-12-19 08:16:30.823957194 +0100
Change: 2019-12-19 08:16:30.823957194 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Please, let me know what other information is relevant. I am trying to understand how this works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103947/discussion-on-question-by-constantine-black-ssh-connectionssh-to-user-through).